# Extending ActiveResource Class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, activeresource

Is it possible to extend an ActiveResource class unmarshalled from a response?

Example of ActiveResource request:

```
GET http://www.exampleservice.com/products.json
```

Response

```
[{name:'Product X', price:14.5, features:[{name:'Soft'}, {name:'Green'}, {name:'Heavy'}]}]
```

This response would be unmarshalled to a `Product` object with an array of `Product::Feature` objects. Is it possible to add some custom method/attributes to this `Product::Feature` class?

Comment: Sure, why not? It's just another class.

Comment: But how? Whether the class Product nor the class Product::Feature exists in the current code, because it gets unmarshalled and created by ActiveResource. Where do I put code which extends the class Product::Feature with additional code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question:

I created a new module including my methods and extended each unmarshalled object of `Product::Feature` with it. This looks like the following:

```
module FeatureExtension
  def my_method
    # do something
  end
end
```

Somewhere after I received a `Product` from `ActiveResource` I used the code:

```
@product.features.each do |feature|
  feature.extend(FeatureExtension)
  feature.my_method # Now it is possible to call the method
end
```